# How to deploy rails code using mina

Tags: ruby, deployment, web-deployment, mina

I don't know how to deploy code using mina. Can anybody write detailed steps on how to deploy code with mina step by step?

Answer (score 0):

What did you try already, at which point did you fail? Did you read the mina documentation and/or did you google for tutorials like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mina-to-deploy-a-ruby-on-rails-application ? I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but just writing up a detailed step by step documentation in a Q&A format is not really something to expect.

Answer (score 0):

The readme in the mina project explains all:

https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/v0.3.8/Readme.md